# Slick 3 truncate tables for testing

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, slick-3.0

I need to use my old code with Slick 3 but it is not working and I don't know how to do it.

my old code :

```
database.withSession { implicit s: Session =>
  StaticQuery.updateNA("SET foreign_key_checks = 0").execute()
  val q = StaticQuery.query[String, String](
    "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ?"
  ).apply(dbname)
  for (table <- q) {
    StaticQuery.updateNA("TRUNCATE " + dbname + "." + table).execute()
  }
  StaticQuery.updateNA("SET foreign_key_checks = 1").execute()
}
```

new code with slick 3 :

```
val a = for {
  _ <- sqlu"SET foreign_key_checks = 0"
  s <- sql"SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ${ dbname }".as[String]
  _ <- DBIO.sequence(s.map(table => sqlu"TRUNCATE #${MySQLDriver.quoteIdentifier(dbname)}.#${MySQLDriver.quoteIdentifier(table)}").map(x => DBIO.successful(x)))
  _ <- DBIO.successful(sql"SET foreign_key_checks = 1")
} yield ()

Await.result(db.run(a), scala.concurrent.duration.Duration(1000, SECONDS))
```

errors :

```
com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to lock table `myLocalDB_test`.`schema_version
Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'myLocalDB_test.schema_version' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an example on Github and it seems working now, you can check it from [here](https://github.com/sergigp/horus.scala/blob/1ec4cd99a040ce4eba7ff7347ffefa1e9f227b4f/test/com/sergigp/horus/infrastructure/EnvironmentArranger.scala)

I changed it like that:

```
val truncatesFuture = db.run(
      sql"""SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ${ dbname }""".as[String]
    ).map {
      _.map { case (table) => SQLActionBuilder(List(s"TRUNCATE TABLE $table"), SetUnit).asUpdate }
    }

Await.result(truncatesFuture.flatMap(
  truncates =>
    db.run(
      DBIO.sequence(
        List(
          List( sqlu"""SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;"""),
          truncates,
          List( sqlu"""SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;""")
        ).flatten
      )
    )
), scala.concurrent.duration.Duration(5000, SECONDS))
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to get the tables from `MTable.getTables`.

```
@ import slick.jdbc.meta.MTable 
import slick.jdbc.meta.MTable
@ MTable.getTables 
res91: profile.BasicStreamingAction[Vector[MTable], MTable, Effect.Read] = slick.jdbc.ResultSetAction$$anon$1@61dff30a
@ db.run(res91) 
res92: concurrent.Future[Vector[MTable]] = Success(Vector(MTable(MQName(TEST1.PUBLIC.COFFEES),TABLE,,None,None,None), MTable(MQName(TEST1.PUBLIC.SUPPLIERS),TABLE,,None,None,None)))
```